# How to detect end of scrolling LongListMultiSelector in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have found solutions that describe the ListBox but they are not suitable. **I need a solution for LongListMultiSelector.** My target is lazy loading rows from SQL CE database in application. I can not determine when the user scroll to the lower border of the LongListMultiSelector. It is necessary to load additional rows from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ItemRealized event to figure that out. Take a look at this [MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e/sourcecode?fileId=70245&pathId=2028033945).

Comment: Thank you for help! I studied example. In example Twitter feed batches loading asynchronously for loading **all** feed. Unfortunately this bad way for me. I do not want load all database in memory (even asynchronously). I want to load data, that user scrolled only.

Comment: The sample does not load all in memory. Notice that it calls LoadPage to fetch a specific set of results after figuring out the user scrolled to the bottom using the ItemRealized event.

Comment: Thank you! I was found my problem! ItemRealized event fetched more rows than I tested. After growth test query to 500 items, I discover that ItemRealized was preload 31 rows. My test was small for detect this rule.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352217/longlistselector-wp8-itemrealized-infinite-scrollable-list)